# Cannot able to open second fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

On click of Button I am trying to open second fragment(YourResultFragment.java),
I had a lots but don't know why it is not working , here is my code which I am using

```
public class KnowYourBodyFragment extends Fragment {


    public KnowYourBodyFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_know_your_body, container, false);




        Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Fragment mFragment = new YourResultFragment(); 
                 getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.know_your_body_container, mFragment ).commit();
            }
        }); 

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Is that button click existed in activity or frgament..?

Comment: post your xml content for activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use this Try to replace it with **`Default Container android.R.id.content`**.

```
Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Fragment newFragment = new YourResultFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
            // fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack("tag");

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        }
    });
```

> What is  `transaction.addToBackStack("tag")` ?

Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

Comment: Thanks Buddy it works , But what is this line of code use for , ..            transaction.addToBackStack("tag");

Comment: @SujitSoni If it worked then **accept** and **up-vote** also the answer so it will be helpful to others.

Comment: @SujitSoni Check i have updated for what is `addTobackStack`.

Comment: You need to set `Dynamic Container`  for that using `Frame Layout`.The answer is not wrong what you asked it solved for you.

Comment: I had used Frame Layout in my XML file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112874/discussion-between-sujit-soni-and-jaydroider).